# How to use the Calendar class in Java without importing any package?

Tags: java

```
public class Question
{ 
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int year;    
        Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance(); //Creating the calendar class object
        year = current.get(Calendar.YEAR); //Initializing year with calendar class object
        System.out.println ("Current Year: "+year); // Printing year
    } 
}
```

I have tried this code and it runs when I import java.util.Calendar.
Can it really be done if we do not import the java.util package class?

Comment: Simply no, you need to import every class which is not in the same package as the one the class you're working on is located.

Comment: You may avoid any "import" by using fully qualified class names, e.g. `java.util.Calendar current = java.util.Calendar.getInstance()`

Comment: It is not possible to use the class residing in other package without importing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the fully qualified class in your code. 
With this way it is not necessary to use an import statement.

```
public class Question
{ 
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int year;    
        java.util.Calendar current = java.util.Calendar.getInstance(); //Creating the calendar class object
        year = current.get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR); //Initializing year with calendar class object
        System.out.println ("Current Year: "+year); // Printing year
    } 
}
```